# ADF Dataflows; Do I have any control or influence over cluster startup time. (NOT "TTL")

Tags: azure-data-factory

*Yes, I know about TTL; Yes, I'm configuring that; No, that's not what I'm asking about here.*

---

- Spinning up an *initial* cluster for a Dataflow takes around **5 minutes**.
- Starting acquiring compute from an *existing* "warm" cluster (i.e. one which has been left 'Alive' using TTL), for a new dataflow still appears to take **1-2 minutes**.

Those are pretty large numbers, especially if you have a multi-step ETL process, and have broken up your pipeline to separate concerns (or if you're executing the dataflows in a loop, to process data per-source-day)

Controlling the TTL gives me some control over *which* of those two possibilities I'm triggering, but even 2 minutes can be a quite substantial overhead. (I have a pipeline where fully *half* the execution time is waiting for those 1-2 minute 'Acquire Compute' startups)

Do I have any control *at all*, over how long startup takes in each case? Is there *anything* that I can do to speed up the startup, or anything that I should *avoid* to prevent making things even *worse*!

Comment: The first question you need to ask yourself here is whether or not that start up delay *is actually causing you any issues?*  Are you trying to solve a problem that isn't one?  Data processing in Azure is mostly designed for bigger data sets that would take a long time to process elsewhere, so the cost of a little start up time is worth it for the improved overall processing time, which shouldn't scale up at anywhere near the same rate as your data.

Comment: @iamdave agreed. We're aiming for <90 minute ingestion processes for the full dataset, by the time we've finished, so 10-15 minutes of startup time spread across various dataflows *would* be material, yes. Probably not deal-breakingly so, but still enough that I'd want to do everything I could (and find out about any notable things early on)

Comment: What are your drivers for using data flows and not a different transformation method that doesn't have the same limitations, such as calling Azure SQL or Synapse stored procedures?

Comment: Because the dataflow *are* actually data manipulations, not just simplistic inserts? I wouldn't have said that dataflows and sprocs were interchangable, for the most part? Dataflows are *drastically* more powerful than sprocs.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what Stored Procedures are, as they are *much* more than just inserts.  In the most simple terms, they are saved SQL scripts that you can execute, usually based on some parameters.  These SQL scripts can also transform your data along the way, using the full feature set of the SQL language, which is designed for data manipulation and has decades of development under its belt.  Within Synapse, the source for the data is extended from just the database itself, as an example, allowing querying of data held within a Data Lake.

Comment: I'm fully aware of what Sprocs are. I don't think "have you considered writing the entirety of your ETL migration in SQL instead of using DataFlows" is a useful response in the context of this question. You might as well ask why I don't re-write it in C# or Python. Certainly it *could* be done, but it would negate any purpose in using ADF in the first place.

Comment: *it would negate any purpose in using ADF in the first place* - Not at all.  Data Factory is the Azure version of SSIS, which was also designed with *doing* the ETL in mind.  What many found instead was that it simply can't beat raw SQL performance and was therefore better placed as an *orchestration* tool for running SQL Procedures.  The same - in my opinion - is true of Data Factory; it works *very* well as an orchestration tool, but starts to fall down as a full blown ETL tool.  I have also personally had great success utilising it this way on large scale projects.

Comment: With regard to being a useful response or not, your question basically amounts to "Can I work around a limitation of the tool I am using" and the answer as far as I am aware is "no."  In light of this, I have suggested alternative methods of acheving the same ends that don't have these limitations.  If runtime is a key success factor for your project and your current tool is not fast enough for the way you want to use it, refactoring is a decision you would want to make sooner rather than later if needs be - either into different workflow patterns or into a different tool.

Comment: Re: Using ADF at all. Fair enough :)

Comment: @iamdave re: useful response. I asked "Is there a way to control this property of the tool", and your response is "Don't try to use the tool". That's one available fix; another would be ***a way to actually control the property of the tool***. Which was the actual question asked, and as far as I can tell, you've made no effort to actually address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a new feature in town, to fix exactly this problem.

Release blog:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/how-to-startup-your-data-flows-execution-in-less-than-5-seconds/ba-p/2267365

> ADF has added a new option in the Azure Integration Runtime for data flow TTL: Quick re-use. ... By selecting the re-use option with a TTL setting, you can direct ADF to maintain the Spark cluster for that period of time after your last data flow executes in a pipeline. This will provide much faster sequential executions using that same Azure IR in your data flow activities.

[image]

Comment: Have now actively used this on a Published ADF. It is indeed far faster.

Comment: Microsoft are now enabling QR by default: https://twitter.com/AzDataFactory/status/1478517532373880833